# How to merge two data frames with specific string match in columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match, partial

I have two dataframes `data1` and `data2` which have information like below:

```
dput(data1)

structure(list(ProfName = c("Hua (Christine) Xin", "Dereck Barr-Pulliam", 
"Lisa M. Blum", "Russell  Williamson", "William D. Stout", "Michael F. Wade", 
"Sheila A.  Johnston", "Julie Huang", "Alan Attaway", "Alan Levitan", 
"Benjamin P. Foster", "Carolyn M.  Callahan"), Title = c(" PhD", 
" PhD", " LLM", " PhD", " PhD", " CPA", " MS", " PhD", " PhD", 
" PhD", " PhD", " PhD"), Profession = c("Assistant Professor", 
"Assistant Professor", "Instructor", "Assistant Professor", "Associate Professor and Director", 
"Instructor", "Instructor", "Associate Professor", "Professor", 
"Professor", "Professor", "Brown-Forman Professor of Accountancy"
)), row.names = c(8L, 18L, 25L, 36L, 49L, 50L, 56L, 69L, 71L, 
82L, 88L, 89L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like below:

[image]

```
dput(data2)

structure(list(ProfName = c("Blandford, K     ", "Okafor, A     ", 
"Johnston, S     ", "Rolen, R     ", "Attaway, A     ", "Xin, H     ", 
"Huang, Y     ", "Stout, W     ", "Williamson, R     ", "Callahan, C     ", 
"Foster, B     ", "Blum, L     ", "Levitan, A     ", "Barr-Pulliam, D     ", 
"Wade, M     ")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

`data2` looks like below:

[image]

I wanted to merge two dataframes, but the names look different. Only a specific string is matching between two dataframes with column `ProfName`. The data should be merged and if the names don't have any information it should be empty. If they don't have any information in the columns `Title` and `Profession`, both `ProfName` and `New` columns should have the same name.

I tried using `merge`, but it didn't give the desired output.

```
merge(data1, data2, by="ProfName", all.x=TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

The output should look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

data1 %<>% mutate(lname = str_extract(ProfName, "[A-Za-z\\-]+$"))
data2 %<>% mutate(lname = str_extract(ProfName, "^[A-Za-z\\-]+"))

df <- merge(data1, data2, all.y = TRUE, by = "lname")

head(df)

#          lname           ProfName.x Title                            Profession           # ProfName.y
# 1      Attaway         Alan Attaway   PhD                             Professor      Attaway, A     
# 2 Barr-Pulliam  Dereck Barr-Pulliam   PhD                   Assistant Professor Barr-Pulliam, D     
# 3    Blandford                 <NA>  <NA>                                  <NA>    Blandford, K     
# 4         Blum         Lisa M. Blum   LLM                            Instructor         Blum, L     
# 5     Callahan Carolyn M.  Callahan   PhD Brown-Forman Professor of Accountancy     Callahan, C     
# 6       Foster   Benjamin P. Foster   PhD                             Professor       Foster, B
```

Comment: could you please keep the `ProfName.y` in `ProfName.x` for the rows which don't have `title` and `Profession`

Comment: I don't quite follow? Do you want to fill in `ProfName.x` with the corresponding value from `ProfName.y` if `Title` and `Profession` are `NA`? That'd be `df$ProfName.x <- ifelse((is.na(df$Title) | is.na(df$Profession)), df$ProfName.y, df$ProfName.x)`.

Comment: Yes, thanq very much.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(secName = trimws(gsub('(.*)\\s(.*)$', '\\2', ProfName))) %>% 
+   right_join(df1 %>% mutate(secName = trimws(gsub('(.*)(, .)', '\\1',ProfName))) %>% rename(new = ProfName)) %>% 
+   mutate(ProfName = coalesce(ProfName, new)) %>% 
+   select(-secName)
Joining, by = "secName"
               ProfName Title                            Profession                  new
1   Hua (Christine) Xin   PhD                   Assistant Professor          Xin, H     
2   Dereck Barr-Pulliam   PhD                   Assistant Professor Barr-Pulliam, D     
3          Lisa M. Blum   LLM                            Instructor         Blum, L     
4   Russell  Williamson   PhD                   Assistant Professor   Williamson, R     
5      William D. Stout   PhD      Associate Professor and Director        Stout, W     
6       Michael F. Wade   CPA                            Instructor         Wade, M     
7   Sheila A.  Johnston    MS                            Instructor     Johnston, S     
8           Julie Huang   PhD                   Associate Professor        Huang, Y     
9          Alan Attaway   PhD                             Professor      Attaway, A     
10         Alan Levitan   PhD                             Professor      Levitan, A     
11   Benjamin P. Foster   PhD                             Professor       Foster, B     
12 Carolyn M.  Callahan   PhD Brown-Forman Professor of Accountancy     Callahan, C     
13    Blandford, K       <NA>                                  <NA>    Blandford, K     
14       Okafor, A       <NA>                                  <NA>       Okafor, A     
15        Rolen, R       <NA>                                  <NA>        Rolen, R     
>
```

Data used:

```
> df
               ProfName Title                            Profession
8   Hua (Christine) Xin   PhD                   Assistant Professor
18  Dereck Barr-Pulliam   PhD                   Assistant Professor
25         Lisa M. Blum   LLM                            Instructor
36  Russell  Williamson   PhD                   Assistant Professor
49     William D. Stout   PhD      Associate Professor and Director
50      Michael F. Wade   CPA                            Instructor
56  Sheila A.  Johnston    MS                            Instructor
69          Julie Huang   PhD                   Associate Professor
71         Alan Attaway   PhD                             Professor
82         Alan Levitan   PhD                             Professor
88   Benjamin P. Foster   PhD                             Professor
89 Carolyn M.  Callahan   PhD Brown-Forman Professor of Accountancy
> df1
               ProfName
1     Blandford, K     
2        Okafor, A     
3      Johnston, S     
4         Rolen, R     
5       Attaway, A     
6           Xin, H     
7         Huang, Y     
8         Stout, W     
9    Williamson, R     
10     Callahan, C     
11       Foster, B     
12         Blum, L     
13      Levitan, A     
14 Barr-Pulliam, D     
15         Wade, M     
>
```